# How to get the number of JMS messages in a Topic

Tags: jboss, jms, messaging, subscriber

How do I get the number of JMS messages waiting to be consumed by a specific JMS message subscriber? I use the Topic model (publish/subscribe) and not the Queue model.

I want my MDB (message driven bean) to be able to figure out this information about the topic it listens to. To be clear; I want my MDB to get the number of messages waiting to be consumed.

I can't find any information in either on Internet or the documentation :(

I use JBoss Messaging 1.4.4.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, JMS does not specify anything to count the number of messages in a destination.

You need to use JMX for this. Check out the [MBean attributes of the Topic MBean](http://labs.jboss.com/file-access/default/members/jbossmessaging/freezone/docs/userguide-1.4.4.GA/html/configuration.html#conf.destination.topic.attributes) in the documentation and/or the java documentation of [TopicMBean#getMessageCounters()](http://labs.jboss.com/file-access/default/members/jbossmessaging/freezone/docs/javadoc/api-1.4.0.SP1/org/jboss/jms/server/destination/TopicMBean.html). The `depth` attribute of `MessageCounter` should be what you're looking for. But, to be honest, I don't know what you're gonna do with this information and if this has a sense for a Topic. A message will stay in a Topic as long as it hasn't been delivered to all subscribers and each subscriber typically hasn't any knowledge of its peers. So how would one MDB interpret a count of messages?

Also note that I couldn't find this MBean in JBoss Messaging 2.0.0.alpha1's [javadoc](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossmessaging/freezone/docs/javadoc/api-2.0.0.alpha1/index.html?overview-summary.html). I don't know if it has been deprecated (according to the code in 1.4, it wasn't) or if the documentation is not up to date (after all, it's the alpha1 javadoc and I couldn't find a link for beta4).

**EDIT:** As skaffman pointed out, JBoss Messaging has been rebranded as HornetQ. It looks like there have been some changes in the API but concepts still apply. The documentation is [here](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq/docs.html).

Comment: JBossMessaging 2 has been rebranded as HornetQ, and it's currently at beta 5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

The reason why I want this value is because I connect the topic to a system where I monitor some parameters. One of these is "how many messages are left to process for each topic subscriber".

Mayby there is a better way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not with the JMS API. The internal JBossMessaging API may expose that information, but you'll have to go looking through that documentation to find it.